# How to implement mysql2 with promises aync or await

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, mysql2

Ive started learning nodejs/ express and in building a web app I decided to use mysql2. I've been following tutorials on how I get it all working and it all seemed to work fine until I discovered promises. To cut a long story short I've now started to understand the value of promises, however, when I tried to alter my code to accommodate them I did not get the same result.

my previous functions would look like this.

```
 function checkIfLogedIn(req,res,next){
let membershipnumber = req.session.membershipno;
if(req.session.loggedin){

    db.query('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE membershipnumber = ?', [membershipnumber], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            response.send('Error connecting to the database '+error);
        };
        if (results.length > 0) {
           

            
            req.user = { 
                name: '${results[0].first_name} ${results[0].last_name}',
                membershipnumber: results[0].membershipnumber,
                customer_id: results[0].id
            }
        }
        
        next();
    });
}


}
```

This worked fine. In the attempt to implement promises I first changed my database file

```
const mysql = require('mysql2'); 
//const mysql = require('mysql2/promise'); 


/////////////////////////////////////////////
//local SQL connection
/////////////////////////////////////////////
module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : 'letsgetkinky',//
database : 'nodelogin'
});
```

Then in my function, i have done this as a test

```
    const db = require('../../database')

async function checkIfLogedIn(req,res,next){
let membershipnumber = req.session.membershipno;
if(req.session.loggedin){

    const data = await db.query('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE membershipnumber = 4');
    console.log(data);
    }


   }
```

This results in an error below

```
Error: You have tried to call .then(), .catch(), or invoked await on the result of query that is not a promise, which is a programming error. Try calling con.promise().query(), or require('mysql2/promise') instead of 'mysql2' for a promise-compatible version of the query interface.
```

Im not sure where im going wrong with this, I've tried following the documentation but it doesn't seem to work or be consistent. when i change mysql2/promise it then tells me that the function query does not exist. I would really like to understand where im going wrong on this and how i should be interpreting the documentation as it looks as though there are multiple ways of achieving this.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation [Using Promise Wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#user-content-using-promise-wrapper), the promise version of `mysql.createConnection` returns a Promise, not the connection directly. So  `db ` would be a Promise in your case when you use `require('mysql2/promise')`, if you use `require('mysql2')` the `db.query` is not Promise based.

Comment: @t.niese when you say it returns a promise and not a connection what is the exact definition of the 2 and how do I differentiate them. Unfortunately when I read the guide it doesn't stand out straight away how I should be approaching this.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, i managed to resolve my own issue. My database file seemed to be causing the issue. Im yet to fully understand why but nevertheless I have managed to achieve using `await` in my functions. Instead of `createConnection` which apparently returns a promise I used `createPool`. With this, I could then do `const [fields,rows] = await db.query('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE membershipnumber = 4');`

database.js file

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : 'letsgetkinky',
database : 'nodelogin'
});
module.exports = pool.promise();
```